# Is it possible to rearrange this for x?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Is it possible to rearrange
$\tan(y) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+C}$  for x, where C is a constant?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tan(y) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+C} \\  \implies \frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+C} \\ \implies \sin(y)(\cos(x)+C) = \sin(x)\cos(y) \\ \implies \sin(y)\cos(x)+C\sin(y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) \\ \implies \sin(y)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(y)=-C\sin(y) \\ \implies \sin(y-x)=-C\sin(y) \\ \implies y-x = \arcsin\left[-C\sin(y) \right] \\ \implies x = y-\arcsin\left[-C\sin(y) \right]$$

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you